# How to pass weights to mean squared error in keras

Tags: keras

I am trying to approach a regression problem, which is multi label with 8 labels for which i am using mean squared error loss, but the data set is imbalanced and i want to pass weights to the loss function.Currently i am compiling the model this way.

```
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), metrics=['mse', 'acc'])
```

Could someone please suggest if it is possible to add weights to mean squared error,if so, how could i do it?

Thanks in advance

The labels look like so

[image]

#

```
model = Sequential()    
model.add(effnet)
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(8,name = 'nelu', activation=elu))
model.compile(loss=custom_mse(class_weights), 
optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), metrics=['mse', 'acc'])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense, Conv1D, LSTM, TimeDistributed
import keras.backend as K


# custom loss function
def custom_mse(class_weights):
    def loss_fixed(y_true, y_pred):
        """
        :param y_true: A tensor of the same shape as `y_pred`
        :param y_pred:  A tensor resulting from a sigmoid
        :return: Output tensor.
        """
        # print('y_pred:', K.int_shape(y_pred))
        # print('y_true:', K.int_shape(y_true))
        y_pred = K.reshape(y_pred, (8, 1))
        y_pred = K.dot(class_weights, y_pred)
        # calculating mean squared error
        mse = K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
        # print('mse:', K.int_shape(mse))
        return mse

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(8, (1), input_shape=(28, 28)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(8))

# custom class weights
class_weights = K.variable([[0.25, 1., 2., 3., 2., 0.6, 0.5, 0.15]])
# print('class_weights:', K.int_shape(class_weights))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_mse(class_weights), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Here is a small implementation of a custom loss function based on your problem statement

- You find more information about keras loss function from [losses.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py) and also check out its official documentation from [here](https://keras.io/losses/)
- Keras does not handle low-level operations such as tensor products, convolutions and so on itself. Instead, it relies on a specialized, well-optimized tensor manipulation library to do so, serving as the "backend engine" of Keras. More information about [keras backend](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py) can be found here and also check out its official documentation from [here](https://keras.io/backend/)
- Use K.int_shape(tensor_name) to find the [dimensions of a tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/shape).

Comment: hey i have updated the question, i have given the label information now, will your answer still work?

Comment: `  (1) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [8,8] vs. [3,8]
         [[{{node training/Adam/gradients/loss/nelu_loss/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]]`

Comment: I believe the problem of incompatible shapes is occurring while calculating the **K.dot**. Can you please share me the whole code so that I can debug it and get it fixed? Otherwise, it would be difficult for me to get you a perfectly workable solution.

Comment: I have made a small change while calculating **K.dot**. It should work now. You can also use the `K.init_shape(tensor_name)` to get the shape of the tensor and make necessary modification in shapes if required.

Comment: hey ,ValueError: The model cannot be compiled because it has no loss to optimize.
any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to compile it from your end?

Comment: Yes, I had compiled the code at my end. If you are facing any problem in compiling the code pls don't hesitate to contact me.

Comment: Great! :) Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

First create a dictionary of how much you want to weight each class, for example:

```
class_weights = {0: 1,
                 1: 1,
                 2: 1, 
                 3: 9, 
                 4: 1...} # Do this for all eight classes
```

Then pass them into model.fit:

```
model.fit(X, y, class_weight=class_weights)
```

Comment: i have only 0 and 1 as classes

Comment: In that case you only need class_weights = {0: <weight 1>, 1: <weight 2>}. No need to go around implementing custom losses and adding 20 lines to your code haha